# How attach png to html later

Tags: html, image, gmail, png, attachment

I send an html letter with images. Some files appear in attachments, and some do not. What does it depend on. I attach these files identically.
Thanks for the answer.

In later:

```
   <img src="{% if not mail %}/img/{%else%}cid:%endif%}email_my1.png"/>
   <img src="{% if not mail %}/img/{%else%}cid:%endif%}email_my2.png"/>
```

Comment: where do you have those images.

Comment: at my computer.

Comment: You need to upload those images online. try this `https://imgbb.com/`

Comment: Thank you.
But I can not correctly explained.
I have all the pictures in httml. But half of them are added in the attached ones. And half is not added. How it works?